# SimpleDateFormat is not returning the expected value in unit test

Tags: java, android, android-studio, unit-testing, kotlin

I have a logic to extract the exact time from the given date (e.g: `12:00 PM`).

At the end of the logic, I'm using the `SimpleDateFormat` to parse the date.
When I run the code on the Android devices everything is working fine.
Also when I run the unit tests on my MacBook, windows os, and Bitbucket pipeline all the tests are passed.
But, when I run the unit tests on the `MacBook M1-pro 2021` with the same Android studio and codebase one of the tests is failed.

This is the part of the code to format the date:

```
val output = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a")
return output.format(date)
```

The expected result is something like `12:00 PM` which is totally fine in those scenarios I mentioned.

[this is the UI on my Android device:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yknia.jpg)

But on the `MacBook M1-pro 2021` test fails because the formatter returns the `12:00 p.m.`:

```
expected: 12:00 PM
but was : 12:00 p.m.
```

[This is the result of the unit test on MacBook M1-pro 2021](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyZxv.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you are implicitly relying on the JVM’s current default locale, and that locale differs between your various test environments.

Or you are using different versions of Java or Android which have different definitions of the locale rules.

And, another problem: You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

The *java.time* classes are bundled with Java 8+, and with Android 26+. For earlier Android, use the latest tooling to provide most of the *java.time* functionality via “API desugaring”.

Convert your legacy `java.util.Date` class to its replacement `java.time.Instant` by calling new conversion methods added to the old classes.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;
```

Adjust into your desired time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Extract the time portion, the focus of your Question.

```
LocalTime lt = zdt.toLocalTime() ;
```

Automatically localize the output. Specify the `Locale` explicitly. The `Locale` determines the human language and cultural norms to apply in localizing.

```
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime( FormatStyle.SHORT ).withLocale( locale ) ;
String output = lt.format( lt ) ;
```

Be aware that [Java 9 changed its default behavior](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/252) to use the vastly richer set of locale definitions in the [Common Locale Data Repository (CLDR)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Locale_Data_Repository) provided by the Unicode Consortium. This change may result in some differences such as your AM/PM formatting. Also, the CLDR data continues to evolve, so later versions may change some rules.

Android may also have changed the rules across versions, but I don’t know the history there.

I suggest you not worry about such minor differences in localized formatting. But if you insist, then you’ll need to:

- Control for the `Locale` on which your code depends either implicitly or explicitly.
- Control for the source and version of the locale rules/definitions
  used by that `Locale`.

Comment: Thank you for the Answer, I tried multiple ways but the problem is just happening on the Apple products with the M1 chip architecture.
All the Android devices, Laptops with the Intel CPU, and Bitbucket pipeline are working fine.
But, MacBook M1 Pro and Mac Studio M1 Max had this issue.

Comment: @MohammadFeyzian I seriously doubt this is an issue specific to Macs with Apple Silicon. Update your Question to show version of Java you are using, and from what vendor you obtained that JDK, and  **the default `Locale`**  for each of those machines. I would bet money your issue is a feature, not a bug. Different locales use different text for AM/PM. And the text used by each locale occasionally changes as the locale definitions change from time to time, and therefore change between versions of Java. Jumping to the conclusion that this is an M1 bug is doing a disservice to yourself.

Comment: I just tried the `DateTimeFormat.forPattern("E")` from the Joda library to format the Date and I faced the same issue while running the unit tests on the Apple Mac Studio:
`expected: Tue`
`but was :   Tue.`
But this is not an issue when I run the unit tests on the Bitbucket pipeline.

Comment: @MohammadFeyzian Without verifying the `Locale` in play, you are just wasting your time (and mine), like a dog chasing its tail. **[`Locale.getDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html#getDefault()) is your friend here.** Or, conversely, use the code I posted in the Answer showing how to *explicitly* specify a particular locale, and then see if results vary.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
val currentTime = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())
```